# Bootstrap Responsive Photo Grid

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

What is the best way to create a photo grid, which can be adjusted based on screen size, where there is no space between photos and a maintained aspect ratio? I want to bring up the second row in the photo so that all blue is covered.

Thank you!

```
<main id="primary" class="site-main container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-primary"><img width="1280" height="839" src="paragliding-52e7d74449_1280.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="paragliding-52e7d74449_1280.jpg 1280w, paragliding-52e7d74449_1280-300x197.jpg 300w, paragliding-52e7d74449_1280-1024x671.jpg 1024w, paragliding-52e7d74449_1280-768x503.jpg 768w"
                sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px" /></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-primary"><img width="600" height="902" src="aaron-taylor-johnson.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="aaron-taylor-johnson.jpg 600w, aaron-taylor-johnson-200x300.jpg 200w"
                sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" /></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-primary"><img width="1280" height="853" src="violin-53e1d2434b_1280.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="violin-53e1d2434b_1280.jpg 1280w, violin-53e1d2434b_1280-300x200.jpg 300w, violin-53e1d2434b_1280-1024x682.jpg 1024w, violin-53e1d2434b_1280-768x512.jpg 768w"
                sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px" /></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-primary"><img width="1280" height="839" src="paragliding-52e7d74449_1280.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="paragliding-52e7d74449_1280.jpg 1280w, paragliding-52e7d74449_1280-300x197.jpg 300w, paragliding-52e7d74449_1280-1024x671.jpg 1024w, paragliding-52e7d74449_1280-768x503.jpg 768w"
                sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px" /></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-primary"><img width="600" height="900" src="ariel-camacho.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="ariel-camacho.jpg 600w, ariel-camacho-200x300.jpg 200w"
                sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" /></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-primary"><img width="600" height="900" src="laz-alonso.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="laz-alonso.jpg 600w, laz-alonso-200x300.jpg 200w"
                sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" /></div>
    </div>
    </main>
<!-- #main -->
```

[image]

Comment: Best way to implement such grid is to use Masonry grid.
Here is the link https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Comment: @akes406
Well if you wanna do it just through HTML,
There's one simpler way to do that.Simply put the images in the same `col` right where you want it.

Comment: Thanks all! @TopWebGhost Went with Masonry, very simple :)